# Constraining Eager Loads retornando sem filtrar

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

Estou com um problema com [eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads) no Laravel 5.4.24. Seguindo a documentação, eu adicionei o código:

```
$profiles = Profile::with(['platforms' => function ($query) {
                $query->where('name', 'PC');
            }])->get();
```

O retorno esperado era uma *Collection* apenas com *Profiles* que tenham *Plataform name* = *PC*.
Ao invés disso eu recebi todos os registros do meu banco, onde o correto seria receber 37 registros. Como exibido na query abaixo:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM db.profiles PROF
INNER JOIN db.platform_profile PLATPROF ON (PROF.id = PLATPROF.profile_id)
INNER JOIN db.platforms PLAT ON (PLATPROF.platform_id = PLAT.id)
WHERE PLAT.name = 'PC';
```

[image: Retorno do Workbench da query rodada]

O que estou deixando passar? Alguém poderia me ajudar com isso?

Model Profile:

```
class Profile extends Model
{
    public function platforms()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Platform')->withTimestamps();
    }
}
```

Model Platform:

```
class Platform extends Model
{
  public function profiles()
  {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Profile')->withTimestamps();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No lugar de [with](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading), coloque [`whereHas`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence), para que possa filtrar os dados mediante a relação e trazer todos os `Profile` pelo filtro:

```
$profiles = Profile::whereHas('plataforms', function($query)
           {
               $query->where('name','PAC'); 
           })
           ->get();
```

Vale lembrar que nada impede a utilização dos dois comandos que traram também o resultado mediante os filtros, porém pela sua pergunta é obrigatório a utilização do [`whereHas`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence):

```
$profiles = Profile::with(['platforms' => function ($query) 
           {
               $query->where('name', 'PC');
           }])
           ->whereHas('plataforms', function($query)
           {
               $query->where('name','PAC'); 
           })
           ->get();
```

<sub>***Referencias***</sub>

- [Querying Relationship Existence](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence)
- [Laravel - Eloquent “Has”, “With”, “WhereHas” - What do they mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30232227/6797930)
- [Eager Loading - with](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading)

Comment: Funcionou do jeito esperado. Obrigado pela resposta!